# Zepp OS UI Component Documentation

Tags: javascript

i realy would like to develop a app for Huamis Zepp OS.
The Hello World example works for me but i could not find a really documentation about UI Development and which ui elements exist.
Does anybody know where i can find this ?

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

My Fault,
found the documentation on:

https://docs.huami.com/docs/reference/device-app-api/hmUI/widget/TEXT/

What i also found out is that only with the web studio on https://studio.huami.com you get code completion.

In other IDES (e.g. VS Code/WebStorm) there is no code completion and currently no plugin to add code completion.